# Is there Ajax function or a way to get intersection value

Tags: php, mysql

I'm developing a new Web Application, and want to print invoices returned from mysql database but not as it is.

ex: i've a table that includes 
product type, quantity and price, with below values:

```
Mango, 1,  10
Apple, 5,  20
Mango, 2,  5
Apple, 10, 20
```

i need a ajax/php/sql code that gets same product with same price so it will get Apple with price 20 then sum all apple quantity and keeps values without intersection as is, so result to be

```
Apple, 15, 20
Mango, 1,  10
Mango, 2,  5
```

then to print values on PDF.

Comment: Share your your code please

Comment: `SELECT fruit, price, SUM(quantity) FROM fruits GROUP BY fruit, price`

Comment: @sammitch it works, Thank you it is much appreciated and thank you all for your support

Answer (score 0):

i don't have enough table data and i can't figure out what your trying to do so just positing this from what i understand. Ok this much i understood you have a table that contain products for some reason your storing same product in several places (obviously huge miss take because data reputation for now let's forget that) now you need a query to calculate the sum of product

```
SELECT fruit_name,price,SUM(quantity) FROM fruits_table GROUPED BY fruit_name;
```

Now i am going to tell how should you handle this according to my experience 
 First you need to store your product details and stock(quantity) information in 2 separate tables 
   **Products Table**

```
Products_id  Products_name

1            Mango

2            Apple

3            Grapes
```

Products Stock

```
  Product_id    Stock

   1              5

   2             10

   3              5
```

Now form this type of table structure you can easily access information and you don't need any SUM(). and if you need to store information about product receiving you have to create another table and sore them in that